Do you have idioms with "as simple as ..."?
I know that we have

as easy as anything/as pie/as ABC/as falling off a log: ​(informal) very easy or very easily
The whole procedure is as easy as ABC.
Fooling him was as easy as falling off a log.

So, "easy" is like you don't need much effort to do something.
But "simple" is like you don't need many steps or things to do something.
Do you have idioms with "as simple as ..."?
For example, "this app is as simple as pie/ ABC..."

You're making a rod for your own back by choosing to contrast "easy" = you don't need much effort to do something and "simple" = you don't need many steps or things to do something. Anglophones don't have any established idiomatic usages where easy and simple can be compared & contrasted like that. A century or two ago the standard idiom was as simple as a child (you can look up for yourself what simple means there).

Please make clear what work you've already done to find "as simple as..." expressions, such as Google searches, Ngram searches, etc.

@Tom On Ngram there is a vast number of riveting collocations with "as simple as". As simple as rolling off a log, as simple as ABC, as simple as 1 2 3, as simple as anything, as simple as snow, as simple as water, as simple as the birds and the bees, as simple as a butterfly, as simple as breathing, as simple as cut, paste and run, as simple as tic-tac-toe.

In British English (specifically England) the phrase "simple as" by itself is used, especially for a case where there's two options. "Either I'm lying or he's lying. Simple as."

Sure, one can make a distinction between "easy" and "simple". Like I've often said that losing weight is simple: eat less and exercise more. Is that easy? No. Is it simple? Yes.
That said, English speakers often use the two words as synonyms. I've heard "simple as ABC".
"As simple as that." Meaning, the task is as simple as what I just demonstrated or just explained.
